SUPER() method in Python 3.11 - "RuntimeError: super(): no arguments"
I am facing "RuntimeError: super(): no arguments" in Python 3.11 version. I am using PyCharm as a coding console. Could anyone help me resolving the below code :
    class Parent:
    
        def __init__(self):
            print("This is a parenet class constructor.")
    
        def method_p1(self):
            print("This is an parent instance method.")
    
        @classmethod
        def method_p2_class(cls):
            print("This is a parent class method.")
    
        @staticmethod
        def method_p2_static():
            print("This is a parent static method.")
    
    class Child(Parent):
    
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            print("This is a child class constructor.")
    
        def method_c1(self):
            print("This is a child class instance method.")
    
        super().method_p1()
    child_obj = Child()
    child_obj.method_p1()

Error Output : super().method_p1()
    ^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: super(): no arguments


Your indentation is wrong.

What are you hoping the code should do?

The problem is super().method_pl(), the third to last line of code. What are you trying to do with it?
Are you trying to override the parent class method? If so, you would write: def method_pl(): #new function logic here.
Otherwise, I think you should delete it because it does not accomplish anything. Anything indented once inside the class body should be a function definition or a class variable assignment. super().method_pl() does not do anything, inside or outside the class.
